# Move UISlider knob to middle while double tap on it

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

I want to **move** the `UISlider` knob to the middle, or `0.0` value in my case, when the double tap event is occurred on it.

Knob is moving to `0.0` on double tap but immediately it resume to the old position/value.

I have tried the below code. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

  super.viewDidLoad() 

  let eqSlider = UISlider(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 160, 40))
  eqSlider.minimumValue = -12.0
  eqSlider.maximumValue = 12.0
  eqSlider.value = 0.0
  self.view.addSubview(eqSlider)

  // detecting double tap on slider method                
  eqSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(EQViewController.doubleTappedSlider(_:event:)), forControlEvents: .TouchDownRepeat)
}

func doubleTappedSlider(sender: UISlider, event: UIEvent) {
  if let firstTouchObj = event.allTouches()?.first {
    if 2 == firstTouchObj.tapCount {
      sender.value = 0.0
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should use, some other words than position, it seems like you are changing the frames.??

Comment: @Arpit B Parekh I am not trying to change the frame, But I need to set the value for the uislider.

Comment: My question is, you do not need to cast 'sender' to UISlider ?

Comment: Why do not you use gesture recognizer ?

Comment: I don't want to apply gesture to the entire uislider, I need only for the knob. that's why I am not go for gesture recognisers.

Comment: Ok, knob means a point, the dot, by which you can show/see/move the slider?

Comment: Do you want 'Double tap event only on knob'? To make slider move to the middle value

Comment: @Arpit B Parekh yes

Comment: How do you captured the knob event ?

Comment: Please check above code.

Comment: I have seen, but it is touchDown event to slider, not the knob .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the two taps in your double tap will also be acted upon by the slider itself, so after you set its position manually, the user is setting it straight back.

To avoid this, you can add the following line after you set the `.value`:

```
sender.cancelTracking(with: nil)
```

This will "cancel any ongoing tracking" as stated in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicontrol/1618219-canceltracking).

Comment: CAn you explain what it does cancelTracking ?, or the name is self explanationary.